# 401 Unauthorized - Calling an Azure API enabled with AD authentication

Tags: azure, azure-api-apps

I have an API hosted in Azure enabled with AD authentication.When browsing the URL it asks for authentication and when entering the credentials the API works fine. But when calling the API in Postman app with Get method with Basic authentication and Oauth2 authentication methods, getting 401 unauthorized error.

Have taken the client ID, secret key, tenant id.

The APP URI in the Ad app is same as the web app Url without "/ " ending with. 
Have given the sign in and read permission for the API in ad app.

```js
$.ajax({
    "async": true,
    "crossDomain": true,
    "url": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantID/oauth2/token",
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": {
        "Accept": "*/*",
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
        "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    },
    "data": {
        "grant_type": "client_credentials",
        "client_id ": "********************",
        "client_secret": "********************",
        "scope ": "https://graph.windows.net"
    },
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        token = response.access_token;
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://azure.azurewebsites.net/api/example",
            type: "GET",
            "async": true,
            "crossDomain": true,
            dataType: "json",
            useDefaultXhrHeader: false,
            headers: {
                "Accept": "*/*",
                "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
                "content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "authorization": "Bearer " + response.access_token
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Have I missed anything in configuring the AD app for the web app?  Also above code is for getting access token and calling the API using that access token. 
Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you don't share your code how would we investigate your problem? If possible include your code on your question.

Comment: If my answer is helpful, please accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The parameters to get access token is not correct. Since you want to use v1.0 endpoint to access your webapp, you should use `resource` parameter instead of `scope`, and the value should be the same client_id. Also, you shouldn't use [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) in frontend.

[image]